# Facebook Instant Articles with Live Status Not Appearing

Tags: facebook

Last year we have made the needed setup for Facebook Instant Articles publishing with the hope that this will improve the speed and experience of our blog posts when accessed from Facebook. We have submitted them to the Facebook team and they were 'approved', hence got Live status.

After that however they never appeared on Facebook, we wrote Facebook support numerous times but got only canned responses.

It seems like this is popular issue for Facebook Instant Articles https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=994495127325721, but personally I could not understand their reply, so my question is - anyone has an idea or experience on this issue?